# How to use the Yahoo OpenID authentication for a windows store application?

Tags: openid, yahoo, winjs, azure-mobile-services

Am working on a windows store javascript application(html/javascript) and have used windows azure for the backend. Azure supports facebook, microsoft, twitter and google authentication.

Is there a way to perform Yahoo authentication for a windows store app?

Answer (score 1):

Please be more descriptive in your question. What exact service for backend and authentication have you used? Azure Mobile Services or Azure Active Directory Access Control (a.k.a ACS)?

If you've used Azure Mobile Services - there is no out-of-the-box support for Yahoo! authentication. If this is the case, you have to add Yahoo manually and handle everything in your app (which is not AZURE related, but more handling OpenId/OAuth in Windows Store Apps).

If you used ACS, it has direct support for Yahoo Identity Provider.

But since you ask, my guess is you are using Azure Mobile Services. And the answer is that you cannot use the Azure Mobile Services SDK/Backend to authenticate against Yahoo. You have to handle this with custom code in your app.

Comment: Even for the custom code I couldn't find any javascript based yahoo authentication resources. It would be great if you could atleast point me to the right set of resource. Thanks!

Comment: My expertise ends here. And this is not Azure related anymore. You shall seek help with WinJS tag combined with Yahoo and probably OpenId or OAuth.